# Visibility IValueConverter for ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: wpf, silverlight, .net-4.0, observablecollection

I'd like to create a visibility converter which displays content if an observablecollection is empty or null. As this converter will be used on many screens, each collection will hold a different type (T).

How do I get a reference to the ObservableCollection of unknown type. This is what I have so far:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      if (value == null) return Visibility.Visible;
      if (value is ObservableCollection<object>)
      {
        var col = value as ObservableCollection<object>;
        return col.Count > 0 ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
      }
      return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to. Just cast to `ICollection` and get its `Count`.